# How can I add a bathroom fan to the existing end line light switch?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, exhaust-fan

I would like to add a bathroom fan to the existing end line light switch.  I am fine with the switch controlling both the light and fan at the same time as the light only has 14-2 running to the switch and I believe it would need 14-3 or 12-3 if I wanted each of the units to have it's own switch. Correct??  Can I add the exhaust fan onto the existing switch so the switch will turn both the fan and the light on at the same time and if it is possible, how?

Comment: Is the fan going to be a combo fan/light to replace the existing light? Or is it separate? If so, are you able to run a wire from the light to the new fan location?

Comment: The fan is going to be separate from the light.  The way the bathroom ceiling is done, I cannot access the light from behind and cannot run a new wire from the light to the switch.  Or a new wire from the light to the fan.

Comment: If you can't run a new wire from the existing light to where you want your fan to be, then how do you plan on powering the fan?

Comment: Given the extremely low power consumption of LED bulbs, I wouldn't hesitate to switch the fan/light unit together and call it a day. Better: install a digital timer switch.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your only stated question is **YES**. To independently switch 2 different things you need to have 2 switched hot wires, you would have to run an additional wire from the wall switch location to the ceiling location.

The statement that "the light only has 14/2 running to the switch" tells us that one of those wires is a hot lead to the switch, the other is the switched hot that runs back up to the light (unless there are other/more wires that you did not mention).